# %Like% Query in spring JpaRepository for 2 fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this object:

```
public class Menu {
       String menuId;
       String symbol;
}
```

I have create this method in te repository:

```
 List<Menu>  findByMenuIdOrSymbolContaining(String text);
```

but I have this error when I init the app.

```
Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.tdk.backend.persistence.repositories.MenuRepository.findByMenuIdOrSymbolContaining(java.lang.String)! null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name `findByMenuIdOrSymbolContaining` suggests using two parameters, where at least one of them must fulfill some predicate. You would have to declare it this way:

```
findByMenuIdOrSymbolContaining(String menuId, String symbol);
```